# Will my iPhone ring once Lost Mode is deactivated?

Tags: iphone, ios, find-my-iphone

Lost my phone, activated Lost Mode not long after. Wondering if I'm able to take my phone off Lost Mode from iCloud, call it and hopefully it rings? I think I lost it down an embankment.

Comment: Where does Find My iPhone say it is?

Answer (score 3):

Normally if a device is in Lost Mode, you can just play a sound using Find My iPhone directly. Choose the Play Sound option which will play a sound on the device for 2 minutes at full volume overriding silent.

If you still wish to call the device, you can disable Lost Mode and make the phone call normally.